# limiting probability - what matrix to write

Tags: markov-chains

To find the [limiting probability](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/MAT135B/materials/ch15.pdf) you solve the systems of equations:

- $\vec{\pi}=P\vec{\pi}$
- $\Sigma \pi_j = 1$

and my teacher told us "you could rewrite this as matrices". Having just completed a first intro course in Linear Algebra, I'm curious on how you would do that. Guess it's a matter of simple algebra.

Answer (score 0):

$P$ is already a matrix ($n \times n$).  Your first equation is $(P - I) \vec{\pi} = \vec{0}$ where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.  Your second
is $(1,\ldots,1) \vec{\pi} = 1$.  So you get the matrix-vector equation
$A \vec{\pi} = \vec{b}$ where $A$ is the $(n+1)\times n$ matrix whose first
$n$ rows are $P - I$ and last row is all $1$'s, and $\vec{b}$ consists of 
$n$ $0$'s and then a $1$.

The system is redundant, since the sum of the first $n$ rows of $A$ is $0$ (do you see why?); you can leave out one of those rows to get an $n \times n$ system.

Comment: "do you see why" I think I do. It's because P represents a markov chain, thus the sum of its rows are 1. If you subtract $I$ then the sum is 0.

Comment: So I should put A in rref, and then calculate $rref(A)^{-1} \cdot b$ ?

Comment: rref is Reduced Row Echelon Form

Comment: Use whatever method you use to solve $A x = b$.

Comment: Well, I need to find a row that is OK to throw out ("redundant" as you call it). And by doing gauss eliminations, I would be able to see what row is linearly dependent (i.e. redundant). Correct?